# Encountered error while installing rel module

Tags: python, importerror

I am getting an error in the statement:

```
 import rel
```

I did 'pip3 install rel' and this is the error I get:

```
from rel import override, supported_methods, initialize, read, write, timeout, signal, event, dispatch, loop, abort, init, sys, EV_PERSIST, EV_READ, EV_SIGNAL, EV_TIMEOUT, EV_WRITE
ImportError: cannot import name 'override' from 'rel' (/private/var/folders/cl/5n1zfgzd7l9fs28spypxs1jr0000gn/T/pip-install-pn4kekfq/rel/rel/__init__.py)
```

Any help to fix it is highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the homepage for that `rel` library? Could not found it among pip repos.

Comment: @vahdet https://pypi.org/project/rel/#files

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the rel module is available only for python v2.7 but I was trying to install it using default python3.
Installed it using python2 and it works fine now.